# Pass a component with props to be rendered by other component

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble passing a component with props to be rendered by other component.

I want to pass a component with props to be rendered inside the StandardModal Component.

```
const StandardModal = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Modal>
      <Modal.Content>
        {props.content}
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Do you know how to do that?

Best regards,
Joshua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
<StandardModal content={<ComponentFoo propFoo={bar} />}/>
```

Regards,
LA.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the component in prop, code is simply this:

```
const Message = ({ greeting}) => <h1>{greeting}</h1>;

<StandardModal content={<Message greeting={"Hello"} />} />
```